# Insert two row in wordpress database

Tags: mysql, wpdb, wp-insert-post

Hello I am working on a template where I have to grab some value and insert them in my own created table in wordpress database. Now as I dont know how to insert record in wordpress database , so i am trying it on my local server for practice. my temlate file is:

```
<?php
/**
   Template Name: Injection.
 */
get_header();
?>
<form method="post" action="">
Album: <input type="text" name="album" />
Artist: <input type="text" name="artist" />
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
 global $wpdb

 $album=$_POST['album'];
 $artist=$_POST['artist'];

 $wpdb->insert( 'music', array( 'album' => $album, 'artist' => $artist ), array( '%s', '%s' ) )
}
?>
```

and here I have a strange problem If I dont use $wbdb class here then my temlate file data show on front end but when I used $wpdb for insertion then it show nothing on front end.

So do you have any suggestion for what should I do for Insert data in mysql.

Thanks

Comment: Not show nothing due the parse error 'global $wpdb' - no ';' at the end of line...

Comment: yes you were right... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
#global $wpdb
```

Comment those lines.. you don't need it. $wpdb quite global in any template file.

BTW, do you really want's to make such form in your tempalte file? 0_o

Comment: no just test to insertion in wordpress

Comment: I am new in wordpress and I required these type info...so +1